Sending data from Excel to MaxMSP over http links
I'm trying to figure out a way to send data from Excel (or Google Sheets) to MaxMSP in order to trigger some audio.
Essentially it just needs to send a file name (or a link containing the filename will do) to Max so I'm wondering if a hyperlink might be a simple way to do this?
The reason I'm wondering about hyperlinks is the file names are somewhat dynamic. Files can be added or names can be changed and since there's a formula for making links in Excel, it seems like a simple way to acheive this.
It only needs to be over localhost and there is a UDP receive object in Max which seemed like it would be helpful for what I'm trying to achieve, but the gaps in my knowledge (which I'm sure you can tell are large) mean I have hit a wall.
If anyone can shed any light on the situation, I would be eternally grateful.
Creating hyperlink in Excel with the localhost port number matching the UDP receive in Max, hope it would receive lilterally anything. Noting happened

The first thing that comes to mind is using a qmetro object to regularly send bangs to a filedate object that is pointed to the path of your Excel file, stored in the csv format.
Whenever the date changes, you can (re-)load the file using the read message to the text object, and then read lines from it.
